# Unable to get SUM of a nested calculated field in Tableau

Tags: sum, aggregation, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

I am trying to get SUM() of a nested calculated field and not able to achieve it.

I have fields A, B and C. I need to display result for each row as change in A relative to C over time. I am doing that using the formula

(A- previous A)*(previous B/previous A) / previous C.

previous meaning value of same category from previous date. So tableau formula looks like this:

(SUM(A)-LOOKUP(SUM(A), -1))*(LOOKUP(SUM(B),-1)/LOOKUP(SUM(A),-1))/(LOOKUP(MIN(C),-1))

Applying this formula, result looks right for individual rows but the sum of individual rows is incorrect as it is not adding up the calculated value of each row and instead applying formula on the sum of each variable in the formula.

So, expected result is 0.6% but tableau is giving 0.9%.

I tried window_sum() on the calculated field but that returns same result as calculated field.

How can I get the sum of nested calculated field?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a table calc - because you use the lookup() function. Table calcs operate on (I.e. take as input) the aggregated query results returned from the data source. That is  different from other calculations such as record-level, aggregate or LOD calcs — all of which take the original data rows as input. So it sounds like you are mixing concepts.

Table calcs are performed client-side, late in the order of operations. Other calcs are performed server-side, I.e. by the database server.

Table calcs are the only calcs in Tableau that can take order into account. Table calcs only see the aggregated query results that were fetched from the data source.

So you can either:

- Fetch the level of detail you need for your calcs by adding more dimensions to the viz, say with the detail shelf
- Or use custom sql or a database view to write an analytic or windowing query - which can take row order into account in the calculation